# Reload modal-content inside modal on click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this very simple jQuery-script to change modal content based on link. Code:

```
$('#facebook-friends').on('hidden', function () {
  $(this).removeData('modal');
});
```

And then I can control which content will be used, based on the buttons:

```
<a href="facebook-frame.php" id="full-width" data-target="#facebook-friends" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-facebook"></i> Use Facebook</a>
```

It works perfectly! However, I have links inside this `facebook-frame.php` file, and I want all actions to stay within the modal, so that the outside page doesn't reload.

I have tried this solution inside `facebook-frame.php` but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="facebook-frame.php?all" data-target="#facebook-friends" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">
```

This is the modal on my mainpage:

```
    <div class="modal fade hide" id="facebook-friends" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Inviter veninder fra Facebook</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body text-center">
    <p>Loading content...</p>
<p><IMG src="ajax-loader.gif"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Luk</button>
  </div>
    </div>
```

I especially love the "Loading content", as it seems very dynamic.

Is there any way to assign a special command/class/name to links/buttons inside `facebook-frame.php` so that when clicked it will temporary show the "Loading content" and then meanwhile load the requested page (inside `href` attribute)?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, inside `facebook-frame.php` can you just capture all `<a>` (or specific `<a>` classes) click events like so?

```
$(document).on('click', '#facebook-friends a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // show the "Loading content" message
    // load the content and whatever else you need to do
});
```

Note: `.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+. Before that you would use `.live()`.